# Can't connect to Google Compute Instance VNC Server

Tags: google-compute-engine, vnc-server

I followed this tutorial:

> https://medium.com/google-cloud/linux-gui-on-the-google-cloud-platform-800719ab27c5

I opened all ports in the firewall.

```
vncserver
nc localhost 5901
RFB 003.008
```

Ran VNC Viewer (external-ip:5901)

> Timed out waiting for a response from the computer

Comment: Can you run "sudo netstat -lntp" on your instance while the VNC server is running and share the output with us. It should show the server listening on 0.0.0.0. If it says 127.0.0.1 or :: then it isn't listening for remote connections. If it doesn't appear at all, then it's not running properly.

Comment: Not sure what happened but it seems to be working now. Thanks for your input David.